# How do rules of conduct apply when acting in a pro hac vice role in another state?

Tags: united-states, employment, professional-ethics

A lawyer's client sent me a mild threat via text message. I have contacted the attorney on 4 separate occasions requesting an explanation/response from the attorney. They have not responded. Are there any ethics rules regarding this lawyer's conduct and failure to respond? Thx.

Comment: What is the relevant jurisdiction? How is this a *pro hac vice* issue?

Comment: The opposing lawyer is from Texas (where his license is) but the jurisdiction is Florida, I believe. This is an issue with someone based in Florida that I do advisory work. You can read more here:https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/30708/what-recourse-does-an-ex-employee-have-when-commission-wages-are-being-withheld

Comment: The Texas lawyer is representing the Florida guy. I am based in NJ. I asked where he is licensed and he told me this (exactly): "I am licensed in the State of Texas and have been admitted on a pro hac vice basis for a case I am handling in Florida.  I am not licensed as an attorney in Florida."

Comment: I am asking this as a "pro hac vice" issue, because of what the attorney told me. I want to know if there are any rules of conduct for lawyers acting in pro hac vice, that he is violating. Thx.

Comment: @Sizzle In addition to my comments and answer, another possibility is that the attorney might be trying to tire you, to gauge how "desperate" you are for a settlement, or to grasp how averse/serious you are about filing a lawsuit, any of these ultimately aiming at lowballing you in a settlement. Now that you have responded to the attorney's contact attempt (per your comment in my answer), you might want to gear up for legal proceedings: getting acquainted with the procedural law, how pleadings are drafted, how to support your pleadings with the evidence you have, reading case law, etc.

Comment: @Iñaki Viggers Thanks for all the info. Last night I emailed my 4th contact with the attorney. This morning he finally responded...with a proposed settlement that I cannot accept, as is. Additionally, it seems their position is to withhold the $55K owed to me until they secure an agreement. As mentioned by you in my other post (linked above), it is my understanding that this is not proper/legal and should I pursue with a lawyer, I may be entitled 3x + legal fees, should I prevail.

Comment: @Sizzle That's correct. Just beware that both statutes 686.201 and 686.417 refer to *reasonable* (rather than *actual*) attorney fees. This means that a prevailing plaintiff might be reimbursed less than 100% of his legal bills. If you're interested how "reasonable attorney fees" are assessed, see [*Florida Farm Bureau Cas. Ins. v. Gray*, 232 So.3d 478 (2017)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/inflco20171004305) and/or other cases using the "lodestar process". Best luck on your matter.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any ethics rules regarding this lawyer's conduct and failure to respond?

Yes.

A lawyer admitted *pro hac vice* will typically be obligated to follow the Rules of Professional Conduct for both the jurisdiction in which he is barred and in the jurisdiction in which he had been admitted *pro hac vice*.

Both Texas and Florida have substantially adopted the ABA's Model Rules of Professional Conduct, which require a lawyer to act diligently and promptly on his client's behalf. This requires an attorney to act on his client's behalf in a reasonably timely way, which the attorney in your hypothetical sounds like he is not be doing.

By failing to respond to correspondence from an opposing party, an attorney can weaken his client's position or even affirmatively subject his client to new obligations. I'm not sure exactly what kind of correspondence you're imagining, but any attorney worth his salt could come up with plenty of ways that failing to communicate with an adverse party could harm the client: subjecting him to new contract obligations under UCC 2-207, allowing a settlement offer to lapse, pissing off the opposing party enough to move ahead with a lawsuit, or pissing off the judge who eventually handles the case, who will be none too happy to see that one side was being intransigent.

If such a failure to communicate diligently and promptly was not reasonable, the lawyer could be subject to discipline.

Practically speaking, though, none of this is likely very relevant for your purposes. My understanding is that unless you're the client, most states wouldn't even permit you to file any kind of complaint against the attorney based on this type of conduct. The ABA rules do impose obligations on attorneys with respect to their dealings with third parties -- they must be honest and fair, but a violation usually requires a more affirmative act than just failing to respond to your correspondence.

Again, I'm not sure exactly what you're asking about, but if this is a real legal dispute, you should consult a real attorney, as the advice available on the Internet is often exactly wrong.

Comment: I think it's funny and pointless to post on someone else's earlier answer the comment "*This seems pretty incorrect*", and yet hours later paraphrase that person's answer for the sake of "contributing" a "new" one.

Comment: If you really think "yes" is a paraphrase of "no," I'd say that highlights the need for an answer separate from yours.

Comment: It is not the conclusory *yes-no* portion of the answer. It is the substance, such as the lawyer's duty to act diligently *on his client's behalf*, or your statement that "*unless you're the client*" the OP would not be permitted to report the attorney's delay as misconduct. These are nothing more than paraphrases of what I wrote a few hours prior to your answer (and prior to your criticism in the comments). Others can tell the sequence in which *who* wrote *what*; but that's ok, you are entitled to pretend they cannot. No big deal.

Comment: I remain flummoxed by your objection. The substance of our answers are hardly paraphrases, as yours is replete with legal errors: (1) PHV admission typically does, in fact, subject a lawyer to additional obligations (see the ABA model rules), (2) filing deadlines don't address the OP's question (dealing with informal communications), (3) opposing parties and courts, as well as the client, may hold a lawyer accountable for missed deadlines (see FRCP 11, 12, 37, 55, etc.), and (4) courts won't hold a client in contempt when his lawyer blows a deadline.

Comment: Even if the substance of your answer did not include those errors and even if it were identical to mine, your failure to reach the correct yes/no conclusion based on that analysis would still be a serious deficiency meriting a separate (i.e. correct) answer to the question ("Are there any ethics rules regarding this lawyer's conduct?"). The correct answer is "yes"; you answered "no."

Comment: (1) Florida RPC adopted the ABA rules, and I already cited a number of those Florida Rules for you. (2) The one or two rules regarding communications w/the adversary do not apply to OP's situation. (3) Your references to Federal Rules of Civil Proc. (which regard judicial proceedings only) confirm my 2nd and 3rd paragraphs, so commenting that "*This seems pretty incorrect*" is misplaced. (4) The client may also be held in contempt to the extent (if any) to which he contributed to his lawyer's missing of a court-ordered deadline, as I mentioned in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Now to address your latest/additional comment: The OP has a specific concern, which is why he gave specific context. Clearly, the OP is not interested in an "all-encompassing" dissertation of legal malpractice. With that in mind, my answer [in the negative] addresses the OP's specific concern. By contrast, your answer that "*Yes [...] though, none of this is likely relevant for your purposes*" goes in circles only to end up reinforcing the answer [in the negative] that I had posted several hours earlier.

Comment: If going point by point through your errors were going to get us anywhere, I'd begin by noting that you're confusing the ABA's model rules of professional responsibility with their model rules for PHV admission, which "subject that attorney to a higher standard than what local lawyers are expected to meet." I suspect, though, that as with previous questions, I'm just going to get ever more entrenched defenses of your original answer that refuse to confront the contrary authority you've provided. I think maybe we're better off disengaging and just watching to see what answer gets more points.

Comment: To me, giving OPs a useful starting point in regard to their particular legal situation or concern is far more important than overwhelming them with details they don't need "*and just watching to see what answer gets more points*".

Comment: If you believe that an incorrect conclusion supported by incorrect statements of law is a useful starting point, we probably just have different approaches to legal analysis. I'll let the market decide.

Comment: Didn't you just suggest you were going to "*disengag[e] and just watch to see what answer gets more points*"? Then go ahead and stop extending the discussion needlessly.

Comment: I suggested that we might be better off disengaging, but it seemed like you wanted to keep going. I'll disengage now, and you're welcome to have the last word.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any ethics rules regarding this lawyer's conduct and failure
>   to respond?

No. Typically the rules of so-called "professional conduct" are that the lawyer owes diligence to his client, whereas the rules would say nothing about diligence toward the adversary. Pro hac vice does not subject that attorney to a higher standard than what local lawyers are expected to meet.

If anything, a form of "diligence" toward the adversary can be somewhat enforced through the deadlines stated in court rules (or rules of civil procedure) for the various phases or elements of a lawsuit.

From that standpoint, the deadline to file a response (whether it is responsive pleadings, response to a motion, discovery requests, answers to a request for admissions, and so forth) is a way of converting *diligence toward the adversary* into *diligence toward the attorney's client*. That is because the attorney must meet the procedural deadlines for following up with the tasks that representing a client entails: motion/request/other that you initiate through court proceedings.

In any case, the attorney's missing of procedural deadline(s) constitutes misconduct that only his client may denounce (or at least hold him accountable). If the attorney/adversary missed a deadline to comply with a court order, the adversary and/or his attorney might be found guilty for civil contempt and/or be sanctioned.

Comment: This seems pretty incorrect. Do you have any cases to support the proposition that no ethics rules address the lawyer's failure to respond?

Comment: @bdb484 Do you have any basis to argue why this seems "incorrect"? The [Florida RPC](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ethics/fl/code/FL_CODE.HTM) don't suggest failure to respond to a client's actual or potential adversary is contrary to lawyer's ethics. Rules 4-1.3 and 4-1.4 only refer to the lawyer's duty of diligence and communication toward his client; a "mild threat" is unlikely to trigger 4-3.4 or 4-4.1(b); OP is not a disciplinary entity; and it is unlikely that 4-4.3(a) would apply when it is unclear whether the lawyer has filed an appearance in court or that proceedings have even started.

Comment: There has been nothing filed as of yet. The attorney contacted me to propose settlement ideas. Now I have not heard from him in over a week (1 voicemail, 3 emails). Could this just be a signal that he expects me to get an attorney to resolve this? I do not know...because he will not respond.

Comment: @Sizzle (1) You are entitled to proceed in pro per (beginning with the exhaustion of administrative remedies, if any are required prior to filing suit in court), so he shouldn't expect you to get an attorney. (2) He or his client might have changed their mind about the settlement proposal(s). (3) It is also possible that he is failing his duty of diligence with respect to his client; many people denounce [via online reviews or with attorney disciplinary boards] that their lawyer doesn't get back to them, and I've heard of attorneys getting sanctioned by an appellate court for belated filings.

Comment: The duty to communicate with parties adverse to your client is one of the most basic and obvious duties of diligence to the client. Whether they're responding to a legal threat, requesting clarification of a demand letter, proposing to settle a dispute, or making their own legal threats, ignoring those communications rarely improves the client's position and can often affirmatively prejudice the client. But again, if you've got cases saying that the professional-conduct rules don't address the failure to respond to adverse parties I'd love to see them.

Comment: @bdb484 Do you realize that you just confirmed what I wrote in my answer?In few words, that the focus is on the attorney's duty of diligence **with respect to his client**. And failure to respond to the adversary would be misconduct only if it stems from negligence, but not if it's due to a change of lawyer's/client's mind or of their litigation strategy. In OP's situation one cannot even ascertain which is it. I already posted the link to Flo.RPC for you, and I assure you that you will find nothing in the sense that a lawyer's bare failure(s) to respond to an adversary constitutes misconduct.